# Calculating the average of variably sized blocks of numbers within a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In column `A` I have a set of numbers (over 1,000), and I want to get an average of a block of them at a time, (e.g., 10, so `A1:A10` then `A11:A20` and so on) and write these averages into column `B`, such that `B1` contains the average of the first block, `B2` the second block and so on.

Then, in `C1` I would like to have a value which defines the number of rows each average should consider (e.g., 10 = `A1:A10`,`A11:A20`... and 25 = `A1:A25`,`A26:A50`... and so on).

When I change the value of `C1` I want column `B` to update automatically to average using the new block sizes.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. The answers, on the other hand, are quite good.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it without using VBA.  Enter the following formula in B1 and fill down to the last row of Column A:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A" & $C$1*(ROW()-1)+1 & ":A" & ROW()*$C$1)),"")
```

Comment: +1 because I prefer a formula to VBA where ever possible, but note that `IFERROR()` is only available in Excel 2007 and newer.

Answer (score 4):

This code will work, assuming you have value in column A (starting in row 1) and input value is in C1.

```
Sub GetAverages()
    Dim avgCount As Integer, numberRng As Range

    Set numberRng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    avgCount = Range("C1").Value

    For cl = avgCount To (numberRng.Rows.Count - (numberRng.Rows.Count Mod avgCount)) Step avgCount
        Cells(cl, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("A" & cl - (avgCount - 1) & ":A" & cl))
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Note this will only compute an average where there are enough values e.g. if you enter 5 in C1 and you have only have values for A1:A13 then you only get averages for A1:A5 and A6:A10

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

In a module;

```
Function roll()
    Dim i         As Long
    Dim total     As Double
    Dim groupSize As Long
    Application.Volatile
    groupSize = Range("C1").Value
    If 0 = Application.Caller.Row Mod groupSize Then
        For i = 0 To groupSize - 1
           total = total + Application.Caller.Offset(-i, -1).Value
        Next
        roll = total / groupSize
    Else
        roll = ""
    End If
End Function
```

put `10` in `C1`, and in `B1` put `=roll()` and drag down/double-corner-click.