# Adding the next x number of cells in a row together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Each week, I will delete one of the columns (it's a set of forecasts held together by a week number at the head of the column; e.g., this week is week 46).

I want to add the next *x* number of cells together.  This (*x*) may change; I'll use 20 as an example.  This will give me the sum of the next 20 cells in that row.  I then want to do it for the next row below that, etc.

Comment: Could you give an example of your data please?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell exactly what you want without more explanation (I'm unsure what deleting a column weekly has to do with what you want...), but I think you may find this helpful: http://superuser.com/a/300388/76571  Just replace the `AVERAGE` function with a `SUM` function.

Answer (score 1):

if you have data organized by date, try a pivot table to massage it. You can more easily filter in the pivot field and columns, and you get to keep your historical data as a bonus. As you describe multiple values, the data would have to be transposed into one observation per line (as in forecast-monthly-v2.xlsx).

quick example: http://www.well.com/~fl/forecast/

Answer (score 1):

If you want cell `A1` to evaluate the sum of `B1` through `U1` (the next 20 cells in row 1), you could put

```
=SUM($B1:$U1)
```

into cell `A1`.  But this probably doesn’t do what you want when you delete column(s).

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,1,1,20))
```

might be closer to what you want. 
If you want the `20` to be a parameter, enter `20` into cell `Z1` (for example) and put

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,1,1,$Z$1))
```

into `A1`.

Of course any of the above can be replicated into subsequent rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(A1:OFFSET(A1,0,xNumberofColumns))
```

This will return the sum of x number of columns.

Height and Width args are optional and not necessary.

height - [ OPTIONAL ] - The height of the range to return starting at the offset target.

width - [ OPTIONAL ] - The width of the range to return starting at the offset target.